# How much damage is caused by smoking 2-3 cigarettes on a healthy body?

Tags: metabolism, smoking

I do not know how bad does 2-3  cigarettes on the average healthy body.

I do not want to include genetic factors on this issue.

So, maybe there is a study or something on this topic.

Does it cause a real damage, or to this quantities the body recovers.

Comment: 2-3 cigarettes a day/week/year/life?

Comment: This question is way too broad, and, IMO, isn't well-suited for this site. Perhaps [Health.SE](https://health.stackexchange.com/) would be better?

Comment: 2-3 a day, right

Comment: I think it's suited for both of them, but i'll address it there as well.

Answer (score 1):

http://tobaccocontrol.bmj.com/content/14/5/315

2-3 cigarettes could make difference absolutely.  It deals 5 points of damage exactly; just kidding.  Hopefully this study provides some insight.